# Trigger modal from bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap dropdown menu where the links open a modal. All seems to work fine on desktop but the modal won't open on a mobile. I have button on the same page which again open modals and these work fine. Just an issue with mobiles (tried on an iPhone).

```
<!-- Dropdown code -->
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Choose Product <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Open modal 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Open modal 2</a></li>
        <ul>
<div>

<!--Modal code -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could be outside the window on mobile? Have you tried adding logging to see what methods are firing on mobile?

Answer (score 3):

Close you HTML tags, It will work.
Try below run.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <!-- Dropdown code -->
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Choose Product <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Open modal 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Open modal 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!--Modal code -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1-label">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1-label">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't closed `div` and `ul` tags

```
<!-- Dropdown code -->
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Choose Product <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Open modal 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Open modal 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!--Modal code -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1-label">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1-label">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I've recoded the page from scratch and all seems to be working now(?).